# What libraries/how to play wav file on Windows32 in C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wav

What libraries for C do I need to play a wav file on a Win32 system?

And what is the code to use those libraries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Win32 API: [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680(v=VS.85).aspx)

Include library: `Winmm.lib`
Header include: `Mmsystem.h` (include `Windows.h`)
Example:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("recycle.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```