# Clion undefined reference to'__imp_PlaySoundA'

Tags: c++, c

I have tried to add links like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")
```

However, it didn't work.

Then I tried to add this in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
#path
link_directories(D:\\Matlab\\significant_part\\sys\\lcc64\\lcc64\\lib64)

# Link to GLFW, GLEW and OpenGL
target_link_libraries(template PUBLIC
        ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
        ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        winmm.lib)
```

It still didn't work.

I wonder how to use function PlaySound(). Please!

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")

Comment: I believe `#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")` will only work if `msvc` is the compiler.

Comment: For the `CMakeLists.txt` you may want to investigate what CMake generated for CLion

Comment: Please specify your OS and compiler. Also, the exact wording of the error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can't see your entire CMakelists.txt or your .cpp/h implementation. A few things basic things to check:

**source/header sanity check**

- Is your cpp function properly (params and all) defined in the .h?
- Is your cpp source file #included the .h?

**Now for the likely culprit, CMake and library linking.**

- Did you find and include the respective libraries?

  - See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34375667/7484918) about OpenGL and GLFW CMake linking.

Here is a snippet of the code from the hyper-link:

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(LearnGLSL main.cpp gl_core_4_3.cpp)
target_link_libraries(LearnGLSL ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} glfw)
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")int main() {
    Sequent_standings rank = Create();
//    HeapSort(rank);
//    mciSendString("open D:\\1.mp3 alias bkmusic", NULL, 0, NULL);
//    mciSendString("play bkmusic repeat", NULL, 0, NULL);
    PlaySound(TEXT("D:\\2.wav"),NULL,SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Comment: Here is how another user played a .wav using PlaySound(...). https://stackoverflow.com/a/3774354/7484918

Comment: @Race you should edit your question and add that information there as formatted code, instead of posting the same question again.